# How to reset the ng-multiselect-dropdown

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I want to reset the ng-multiselect-dropdown. Is it necessary to put it in a form ?

code -

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <p id = "node">Select a Root API Object - </p>
  <p style="width:50%">
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Select Root API Object'" [data]="dropdownListRoot" [(ngModel)]="selectedItemsRoot" [settings]="dropdownSettingsRoot"
      (onSelect)="onItemSelectRoot($event)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAllRoot($event)">
    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>

  </p>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
 export class HierarchySearchComponent implements OnInit {

 onItemSelectRoot(item: any) {
    this.onlyRootItemSelect = true;  // for cypher also.


    console.log(item); 
    this.rootItem = item;
    this.nodeSelect = true;

    this.rootItemText = this.rootItem.item_text;
    console.log("this.rootItemText = ", this.rootItemText);

  }


  onSelectAllRoot(items: any) {
    console.log("On Item select all" + items);
    this.nodeSelect = true;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is not necessary to put it in form.
Just make the selectedItemsRoot array empty. Call this function resetSelection() from the element/context.
if you are using the button to clear selection, it can be

.html

```
`<button (click)="resetSelection()" >clear</button>`
```

.ts

```
resetSelection() {
this.selectedItemsRoot = [];        
}
```

Comment: It's clear from the selected item list but in form selected item showing the same field. I want to clear the selected items from the ng-multiselect-dropdown field also.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to put it in a form - if you want to clear the selected items, just set the `selectedItemsRoot` object to an empty array. I.e.

```
clearSelection() {
    this.selecteditemsRoot = [];
}
```

And bind that function to a button, or call it with any other method you are using to clear the selection.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using formControlName instead of ngModel then you can use something like this

```
this.myForm.get(formControlName).setValue([]);
```

Comment: Can you help as I am using this way but not refelect on DOM, multiselect still appears as there are some value selected