Ng-multiselect-dropdown values wont Reset after Select
I am trying to reset the values I've selected. This is quotation-form.component.html
This i similar to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53114750/how-to-reset-the-ng-multiselect-dropdown but none of them work for me so far.
                            <ng-multiselect-dropdown
                            [placeholder]="'Select Engine Type'"
                            [data]="this.motor"
                            [settings]="dropDownMotorSettings"
                            (onSelect) = "onMotorSelect($event)"
                            (onDeSelect)="onMotorDeSelect($event)"
                            ></ng-multiselect-dropdown>

                            <ng-multiselect-dropdown
                            [placeholder]="'Select Boat Accessories'"
                            [data]="this.accessories"
                            [settings]="dropDownAccSettings"
                            (onSelect)="onAccessorySelect($event)"
                            (onSelectAll)="onAccessorySelectAll($event)"
                            (onDeSelectAll)="onAccessoryDeSelectAll($event)"
                            (onDeSelect)="onAccessoryDeSelect($event)"
                            ></ng-multiselect-dropdown>

It is wrapped in form tag, and I bind it to this FormGroup:
  quotationForm = new FormGroup({
    customerName: new FormControl(''),
    customerEmail: new FormControl(''),
    contactNumber: new FormControl(''),
    boatType: new FormControl<string>(''),
    boatEngine: new FormControl(''),
    boatAccessories: new FormControl<string[]>([]),
    vat: new FormControl(''),
    discount: new FormControl(''),
    paymentDates: new FormControl<string[]>([]),
    paymentBoat: new FormControl<string[]>([]),
    paymentEngine: new FormControl<string[]>([]),
    deliverySched: new FormControl(''),
  });

I have this function for clearing all values:
  clearAll(){
    // this.quotationForm.controls.boatEngine.reset();
    // this.quotationForm.controls.boatAccessories.setValue([]);
    this.clearDropDownContents();
    this.quotationForm.reset();
    this.selectedBoatType = '';
  }

My data source is this.motor and this.accessories. For this.clearDropDownContents() I've tried these combinations of clearing a string and a string array. But somehow, the view isn't updated.
  clearDropDownContents(){
    this.quotationForm.controls.boatAccessories.setValue([]);
    this.quotationForm.controls.boatEngine.reset();
    // this.quotationForm.controls.boatAccessories.setValue(null);
    // this.quotationForm.controls.boatEngine.setValue(null);
    // this.quotationForm.controls.boatAccessories.reset();
    // this.quotationForm.controls.boatEngine.reset();
    // this.motor = Array.from([]);
    // this.accessories = Array.from([]);
    this.motor = [];
    this.accessories = [];
  }


The resolution was to add [formControl] to bind data to formGroup.
  clearDropDownContents(){
    this.quotationForm.controls.boatAccessories.reset();
    this.quotationForm.controls.boatEngine.reset();
  }


You missing the formControlName for the ngMultiSelect only then the form is connected to the component, to trigger the reset.
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
id="boatEngine"
name="boatEngine"
formControlName="boatEngine"
[placeholder]="'Select Engine Type'"
[data]="this.motor"
[settings]="dropDownMotorSettings"
(onSelect) = "onMotorSelect($event)"
(onDeSelect)="onMotorDeSelect($event)"
></ng-multiselect-dropdown>

<ng-multiselect-dropdown
id="boatAccessories"
name="boatAccessories"
formControlName="boatAccessories"
[placeholder]="'Select Boat Accessories'"
[data]="this.accessories"
[settings]="dropDownAccSettings"
(onSelect)="onAccessorySelect($event)"
(onSelectAll)="onAccessorySelectAll($event)"
(onDeSelectAll)="onAccessoryDeSelectAll($event)"
(onDeSelect)="onAccessoryDeSelect($event)"
></ng-multiselect-dropdown>


I see. I intentionally left formControlName out because I was having trouble filtering data. I get data in this format: {id: 1, name: "accessory name"}.. but I needed to store every name in a string array, so for every select, I just took item.name and pushed it in like so:
let accessories = this.quotationForm.controls.boatAccessories.value || [];
if (item) {
accessories.push(item.name);
this.quotationForm.controls.boatAccessories.setValue(accessories);
And i just popped it from the array on deselect.
